# How does boost::ref work?

Tags: c++, boost

Having read couples of explanations here on StackOverflow, I still don't have a clue to how it works and what it is for. The demos I saw all use `boost::reference_wrapper<int>` as the type, that is, they all wrap `int`, and they also all run prefix op++ to show how it affects the wrapped int in the function template. One expert said the ref wrapper will be cast into the wrapped object if op++ is called on the ref wrapper, but it seems that it's not how it works. Please see the following example that demonstrates what would happen if the wrapped object is not an `int`. You may want to compile it before reading the code, so as to save your precious time.

```
// Build int version: g++ thisFile.cpp -Wall
// Build CFoo version: g++ -std=c++11 thisFile.cpp -DDONT_USE_INT -Wall
#include <boost/ref.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

class CFoo
{
public:
    CFoo(int val) : m_val(val) {}
    CFoo& operator++(void) {
        ++m_val;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    int m_val;
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream& ostrm, const CFoo& param);
};

template <typename T>
void a_func_tmpl(T param)
{
    ++param;
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream& ostrm, const CFoo& param)
{
    ostrm << param.m_val;
    return ostrm;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(DONT_USE_INT)
    CFoo obj(0);
#else
    int obj(0);
#endif
    a_func_tmpl(obj);
    cout << obj << endl;
    a_func_tmpl(ref(obj));
    cout << obj << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the output of compiling.

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 thisFile.cpp -Wall
$ ./a.out
0
1
$ g++ -std=c++11 thisFile.cpp -DDONT_USE_INT -Wall
thisFile.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void a_func_tmpl(T) [with T = boost::reference_wrapper<CFoo>]’:
thisFile.cpp:40:22:   required from here
thisFile.cpp:22:2: error: no match for ‘operator++’ (operand type is ‘boost::reference_wrapper<CFoo>’)
  ++param;
  ^
```

As you can see, it does work if the wrapped type is `int`, but a compile-time error happens if the type is not `int` even if the wrapped type offers op++. It would be highly appreciated (I've been stuck on this for 2 days T_T) if someone can explain what really happens when a method of wrapped type is called on the wrapped ref. Thanks in advance. m(_ _)m

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reference_wrapper` is **really** simple, the easiest way to understand how it works is simply to look at the code. The generator functions, `ref` and `cref` that create a reference_wrapper are even simpler, again, just look at their definitions.

Understanding what it's for is also pretty simple: the intended use of `reference_wrapper` is to pass a variable by reference through a generic API that usually takes arguments by value. That's it.

That's useful when you have wrapped some function or functor in a forwarding API, and want to ensure the forwarding API passes references not values.

For instance, `boost::bind` copies its arguments into the callable object that it returns, and then invokes the target function passing the copied objects as arguments.

e.g. when you call `boost::bind(&func, i)` it returns a functor that contains a copy of `&func` and a copy of `i`. When you invoke that functor, it calls `func` with the *copy* of `i`. So if the function takes a reference, that reference is bound to the internal copy of `i` not to `i` itself. So if you have:

```
void func(int& i) { ++i; }
int i = 0;
auto bound = boost::bind(&func, i);
bound();
assert( i == 1 );  // FAILS!
```

The assertion will fail, because the `int` that gets passed to `func` is not `i` but a copy of `i` stored inside `bound`.

If you actually want the bound function to be called with a reference, you need something that is copyable like a value but implements reference semantics, which is where `reference_wrapper` comes in:

```
void func(int& i) { ++i; }
int i = 0;
auto bound = boost::bind(&func, boost::ref(i));
bound();
assert( i == 1 );  // passes
```

Now `ref(i)` creates a `reference_wrapper<int>` that refers to `i` and so `bound` contains a copy of that `reference_wrapper<int>`, also referring to `i`. When you invoke `bound` it passes the `reference_wrapper<int>` to `func`, which triggers the implicit conversion to `int&`, so that the reference binds to `i`, and `i` gets incremented as desired.

Other examples where you would use `reference_wrapper` are `std::thread` and `std::async` (and the Boost equivalents). They copy their arguments and then pass them to the wrapped target functor as rvalues, so if the functor has lvalue reference parameters then you *must* use `reference_wrapper` for the code to even compile.

Using `reference_wrapper` with your `a_func_tmpl` example doesn't really match the intended use, because the function doesn't take a reference, and you're not calling it through a generic API that would decay references to value anyway. Personally I wouldn't worry too much about why your example works in one case and not in the other, because it isn't the intended use case for `reference_wrapper` anyway. It's more important to understand what it *is* meant for, so you can use it in the appropriate places when necessary.

Comment: -1, does not answer the actual question at all (yes, the reason why it does not work _is_ interesting).

Comment: @JanHudec, I addressed the "I still don't have a clue to how it works and what it is for." part, because IMHO the rest of the question wastes time and effort trying to understand how to misuse the utility.  I think it's better to understand what it **is** for.

Comment: Except that problem is not constrained to misuse of the utility. It can happen with intended use if the generic function in question does not expect it and use `unwrap_reference` explicitly and then it will be quite difficult to understand as the error will come from deep inside some template.

Comment: Usually the intended uses do not call a generic function as the target, you name the specific function you want to call, e.g. `std::thread(&a_func_tmpl<CFoo>, std::ref(obj))` and so the parameter type is pre-determined and the `reference_wrapper` will be converted to the parameter type.

Comment: The information is very detailed. Thanks a lot. Really appreciate your help. Can I put it this way: the purpose of ref wrapper is only to save tedious typing? especially when the template parameter list is long. I can't figure out a case that we can't achieve the same result by specifically specify the template type argument to be a ref type. For example, assume we have a function template `template <typename T> funcTmpl(T param) {..}`. The result of `funcTmpl(boost::ref(obj));` will be the same as `funcTmpl<CFoo&>(obj)`, if the ref wrapper is to be cast into a `CFoo&` inside `funcTmpl`.

Comment: (conti) Without the casting, the ref wrapper would be totally useless, because it doesn't offer interface of the object it refers to. It confused me: why would I ever pass such a thing into a template that I'm not 100% sure how the template would processes it? Because of the information you provide, now I know it shall cooperate with another function/functor that is also under our control, and that function/functor will do the casting. In the case of `bind`, that function/functor is the first param of `bind`. This is how the ref wrapper is supposed to be used. Can I put it this way?

Comment: You're right that the ref wrapper is pretty useless if you don't "unwrap" it again, i.e. cause it to be cast to the reference type, but it's definitely not just to save typing, it supports things that are impossible otherwise. e.g. you cannot use an explicit template argument list with the `std::thread` constructor, so `reference_wrapper` is the only way to pass arguments by reference to the new thread. Also, `bind<void(*)(int&), int&>(&func, i)` would cause the bound object to store an `int&` but that's not the same as `bind(&func, ref(i))`, it would have different (undesirable) behaviour.

Comment: So although you _can_ call some function templates with an explicit template argument list, it still doesn't always solve the problem of passing things by reference, and it's ugly and very inconvenient to have to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Your usage and understanding of `reference_wrapper<>` seems to actually be correct. However, you stumbled over another problem, which obscures that.

The problem is that there is no implicit conversion from `reference_wrapper<CFoo>` to `CFoo&` for the implicit `this` parameter. In this case, this would be needed to find `operator++`. However, it should work fine with a free-standing function that does the same:

```
void bar(CFoo& foo)
{
  ++foo;
}

template <typename T>
void a_func_tmpl(T param)
{
    bar(param); // This allows the implicit conversion
}
```

Alternatively, you can implement operator++ as a free-standing function:

```
class CFoo
{
public:
  CFoo (int val) : m_val (val) {}

private:
  int m_val;
  friend ostream & operator<<(ostream& ostrm, const CFoo& param);
  friend CFoo& operator++(CFoo& foo);
};

CFoo& operator++(CFoo& foo) {
  ++foo.m_val;
  return foo;
}
```

The only problem really is that the compiler doesn't know that it needs to convert from `reference_wrapper<CFoo>` to `CFoo&` to find `operator++` if you define it in the class. The conversion is available, but it isn't asked for.

Comment: Additional difference will appear if `CFoo` is convertible to `CBar`. Then functions taking `CBar` will work on `CFoo` instances, but not on the reference wrapper, since compiler does not try to compose user-defined conversions (I believe it might be fixable by providing suitable templated conversion with appropriate enable-if, but `boost::ref` does not attempt it).

Answer (score 0):

The code fails because `++param` is calling `boost::reference_wrapper<CFoo>::operator++` (because that's what you passed) for which there is no definition.

The interface of `reference_wrapper<T>` has a conversion operator to `T&`, but the compiler does not have a way to deduce that that's what you meant. `x++` means 'call x::operator++', not 'find any old version of operator++ that I can coerce x into'

try

```
++(static_cast<T&>(param))
```

or

```
  T& p = param;
  ++p;
```

Comment: Well, except `x++` **does** mean "find any old version of operator++ that I can coerce x into". The issue is _where_ it looks them up. It looks them up in type of `x`, base types of `x`, visible namespaces and associated namespaces of type of `x`. `T` in `reference_wrapper<T>` is none of those, so it's not looking in `T`.

Comment: You know what I meant :)

Comment: I don't know what you meant and what you wrote is incorrect.

Comment: It does not mean 'find any old...' It means 'search a number of candidates according to a set of rules'. What I wrote was ambiguous but not incorrect.

Comment: But you didn't write "set of candidates", you wrote "`boost::reference_wrapper<CFoo>::operator++`". And while that is one of the candidates, it is by no means what the expression means.